# convert a list of neighbours to a list of connected-nodes-groups?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, recursion

I have a list of neighbours for each node and need to have a list of groups of neighbouring nodes.

The Numbers in the input lists are the indexes of neighbouring nodes.

Example: `[(1, ), (0, ), (3, 4), (2, ), (2, )]`

Would be: `[(0, 1), (2, 3, 4)]`

I believe the solution might be a recursive function?

Comment: This is a kind of [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). Recursion is a good idea, for the DFS/BFS part of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example graph is an undirected graph (all edges are defined in both directions). What you call groups are commonly called [components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

You can use a depth-first traversal to find all nodes that can be reached from a starting node (giving a component), and take the next non-visited node and repeat.

Implementation:

```
def components(adj):
    n = len(adj)
    visited = [False] * n
    
    def dfs(node):
        visited[node] = True
        yield node
        for neighbor in adj[node]:
            if not visited[neighbor]:
                yield from dfs(neighbor)

    for node in range(n):
        if not visited[node]:
            yield tuple(dfs(node))
```

Example run

```
adj = [(1, ), (0, ), (3, 4), (2, ), (2, )]
print(list(components(adj)))
```

This outputs:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`networkx`](//networkx.org):

```
import networkx as nx

lst = [(1, ), (0, ), (3, 4), (2, ), (2, )]

G = nx.from_edgelist((i, x) for i, t in enumerate(lst) for x in t)

out = list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

Output: `[{0, 1}, {2, 3, 4}]`

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I just had to accept the other because it didn't use any external packages :)